# From where am I supposed to install OpenSocial's gadgets.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, yql, opensocial

I am trying to do this tutorial, http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_javascript

and it says to use gadgets.io, but does not say anything about installing it.  Where do I get it from?

I should also say that I am trying to perform the query from a socket.io server.

Answer (score 1):

**gadgets.io** is a javascript service exposed by the OpenSocial API which is available through OpenSocial containers.  OpenSocial containers are used to host 3rd party web components known as **[gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/)** and were originally contributed by Google.

There is no such thing as 'getting' the **gadgets.io** library, as it is exposed to gadgets running on a container.  I'm not familiar with YQL, but I had a look at the link you provided and the code example they demonstrate is meant to be executed within some type of playground environment @ Yahoo I guess - therefore their environment should support gadgets, i.e. an OpenSocial container.

Have a look at the original documentation of the **[gadgets.io.makeRequest](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/remote-content)** in order to see similar examples.  Hope it helps :)